# Python - regex for dir

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex expression but its not working for all cases.

I need it to be able to match any case of the following:

If this word "test_word" is in the statement return true

What I been using hasn't been working

```
('^/[^/]*/test_word/.+')
```

or

```
('^/test_word/.+')**
```

So I'm matching in statements with dirs such as:

```
/user/test_word
/test_word
/test_word/test_word/
/something/something/test_word/
```

and anything you can think of that could happen.

Comment: Why not just use ('test_word')? Does test_word have to be a directory name itself? (is /test_word2/ a match?)

Comment: I have to make a edit to this. Not sure if I should make a new posting.

Comment: Sorry I miss a key requirement...please see additional posting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262426/python-regex-for-dir-of-certain-depth

Answer (score 1):

If you know it's a path and just want to check if test_word is in there you can just use re.search to find "test_word" anywhere in the path, or just if "test_word" in path.

If you want to make sure it's just test_word, and not something like test_words, test_word9 etc., then you can do something like this:

```
import re

dirs = ["/user/test_word", "/test_wordsmith", "/user/test_word2", "do not match", "/usr/bin/python", "/test_word","/test_word/test_word/","/something/something/test_word/", "/test_word/files", "/test_word9/files"]

for dir in dirs:

    if re.search('/test_word(/|$)', dir):
        print(dir, '-> yes')
    else:
        print(dir, '-> no')
```

You're matching a forward slash followed by test_word, followed by either a forward slash or the end of the string / line.

Output:

```
/user/test_word -> yes
/test_wordsmith -> no
/user/test_word2 -> no
do not match -> no
/usr/bin/python -> no
/test_word -> yes
/test_word/test_word/ -> yes
/something/something/test_word/ -> yes
/test_word/files -> yes
/test_word9/files -> no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:/[^/]*)*/test_word.*
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/86

Answer (score 0):

At the end its just this -

```
/test_word/?$
```

In the middle or end, its this -

```
/test_word(?:/|$)
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cR4cZ2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: You want `test_word` as a complete pathname component (not part of a larger word), so either surrounded by slashes or at the start or end of the string:

```
(^|/)test_word($|/)
```

But a better solution would be to break up the pathname into components, then use exact matching:

```
pathname = "/usr/someone/test_word"
return "test_word" in pathname.split("/")
```

Try it.

Comment: Is this case sensitive? How would make non case sensitive?

Comment: You want case insensitive? You never said anything about that. With a regexp, add `(?i)` to the regexp. For exact comparison, lowercase both strings (`test_word` and `pathname`) with `lower()` before splitting and comparing.