# Python- Regex for dir of certain depth

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex expression but its not working for all cases.

I need it to be able to match any case of the following within two levels of depth:

If this word "test_word" is in the statement return true

What I been using hasn't been working

```
('^/[^/]*/test_word/.+')
```

or

```
('^/test_word/.+')**
```

So I'm matching in statements with dirs such as:

```
/user/test_word
/test_word
/test_word/test_word/
```

but false in this example because its beyond two levels. I don't want positive for anything beyond two levels

```
   /something/something/test_word/
```

and anything you can think of that could happen.

Comment: With your examples, are you describing what is currently happening or what you want to happen?  One problem with the first two true examples is that they don't have a trailing slash, but both of your regex require it.

Comment: @aelfric5578, OP is testing with both the first OR the second expression shown which successfully matches the first 3 example directories. However, OP is having problems when `test_word` is deeper in the structure like in the 4th example.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261592/python-regex-for-dir

Comment: Next time, modify your original question instead of starting a new one. There is absolutely no difference to the first one except a level restriction.

Comment: I didn't want people get mad at me for changing the question when they already provided an answer for something else. I been ask to do the opposite in the past of what your asking. Especially in code review. Thank you for your awesome answer though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this,

```
^(?=.*?/test_word)(?!.*?//)\/(?:[^/]*)(?:/[^/]*)?/?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yT4uD1/3)

Comment: That's a useful link.  I've always used pythonregex.com, but that gives much more information.

Comment: This will match `/test_words/blah` ie, where 'test_word' is not the complete name. Otherwise -- Perfect!

Comment: @dawg now it seems ok `^(?=.*?/test_word(?=/|$))(?!.*?//)\/(?:[^/]*)(?:/[^/]*)?/?$` http://regex101.com/r/yT4uD1/4

Comment: inner lookahead asserts that the string `test_word` must be followed by end of the line anchor or forward slash.

Comment: This is overkill and doing it the hard way.

Comment: The OP wants the test word within 2 levels of depth, he didn't say anything about restricting the depth. Your regex won't match `/test_word/test_word/asdf/asfbbbafdsb`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is python 2.7 (haven't worked with 3) you don't really need any libraries just the builtin string functions this is how I approached it:

```
testword = "test_word"
stringToCheck = "/something/something/TeSt_wOrD/"

def testForWord(string):
    if testword in string.lower(): return True
    else: return False

print testForWord(stringToCheck)
```

As you can see it checks for any case because it just checks when all cases are lower case. I'm not 100% sure if thats what you need but I think that should do it :D.

Comment: in *nix system, lower casing every string, especially handling a path, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
lines = '''\
/user/test_word
/test_word
/test_word/test_word/
/something/something/test_word/
/user/test_word/
/test_word/
/test_word/test_word
/something/something/test_word
/user/test_word/more
/test_word/more
/test_word/test_word/more
/something/something/test_word/more
/something/test_word/test_word
/test_wordxx
/something/test_wordxx
'''.splitlines()

import re
for line in lines:
    if re.match('/(?:[^/]+/)?test_word(?:/|$)',line):
        print('YES',line)
    else:
        print('NO ',line)
```

Output:

```
YES /user/test_word
YES /test_word
YES /test_word/test_word/
NO  /something/something/test_word/
YES /user/test_word/
YES /test_word/
YES /test_word/test_word
NO  /something/something/test_word
YES /user/test_word/more
YES /test_word/more
YES /test_word/test_word/more
NO  /something/something/test_word/more
YES /something/test_word/test_word
NO  /test_wordxx
NO  /something/test_wordxx
```

Not sure if you want the 3rd to last one.

Comment: So far all my test cases are correct with your expression. The 3rd one from the bottom is correct.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you not to use regex in such case. what you want here is partial perfect match instead of pattern match, so it's a waste of computation resource. you could do it by simply:

```
import os
filepath = #init
hier = filepath.split(os.path.sep)
print 'right' if hier[1] == 'test_word' or hier[2] == 'test_word' else 'wrong'
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2 levels

```
^/(?:[^/\r\n]*/){0,1}test_word(?:/|$)
```

Expanded:

```
 ^ 
 /
 (?: [^/\r\n]* / ){0,1}
 test_word
 (?: / | $ )
```

For N levels (>= 2)

```
^/(?:[^/\r\n]*/){0,N-1}test_word(?:/|$)
```

Expanded:

```
 ^ 
 /
 (?: [^/\r\n]* / ){0,N-1}
 test_word
 (?: / | $ )
```

Comment: This is a dynamic answer. Thanks.

Comment: Not really dynamic, probably static.